# Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $m = 24n + 51$. What is the largest possible value of the greatest common divisor of $2m$ and $3n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

> Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $m = 24n + 51$. What is the largest possible value of the greatest common divisor of $2m$ and $3n$?

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Euclidean algorithm here, but I don't know where to start. I have that $2m=48n+102$ and $3n=\frac{m-51}{8}$.

The solution for this problem was the following

> \begin{align*}
> \text{gcd}(2m, 3n) &= \text{gcd}(2m-3n\cdot16, 3n) \\
> &= \text{gcd}(2\cdot(24n+51)-48n, 3n) \\
> &= \text{gcd}(102, 3n) \\
> &\leq 102.
> \end{align*}

but I don't understand the steps here... Where do all the equalities come from?

Comment: I think they are using the euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Hint: $2m=48n+102=16(3n)+102$ i.e. $102=2m-16(3n)$ so if something divides both $2m$ and $3n$, it must divide ...

Comment: Also note the solution you have is incomplete. It just shows that the $\gcd$ is $\le 102$ but does not show that its maximum value is *precisely* $102$. For that, you need to find an example of $m,n$ such that $m=24n+51$ and $\gcd(2m,3n)=102$.

Comment: $gcd(a,b)=gcd(a-kb,b)$

Comment: $(3n,2m) = (3n,102\!+\!\color{#c00}{48n}) = (3n,102\!+\!48n-16(3n)) = (3n,102)\,$ by the gcd law in the  linked dupe, i.e.  $\,(3n, a+\color{#c00}b) = (3n,a+(\color{#c00}b\bmod 3n)) = (3n,a)\,$ if $\,3n\mid \color{#c00}b\ $ [e.g. $\,\color{#c00}{b = 48n}\,$ above] $\ \ $

Comment: Setting $n=0$ gives $2m=102$ and so the $\gcd$ is $102$. On the other hand if $x$ divides $48n+102$ and $3n$ then it divides $48n+102 - 16(3n) = 102$, so answer is $102$.

Please note this is not a very good answer but it was just an attempt to speedrun while being self contained :) .

------

As to where the equations in your original post are coming from, they are using what is known as the euclidean algorithm.